# Calculation using timestamp

Tags: sql-server, casting, sql-server-2012, datepart

I have a table containing webpage 'hits' and timestamps associated daily cumulative hits.  Using a 24-hour clock, I want to calculate the "grossed up" hits.  For example:  hits of 10,000 for 2020-07-13 10:10 is 10,000 hits for 10 hours and 10 minutes, or 610 minutes.  Grossing the 10k based on 24 hrs = 1440 / timestamp minutes.  1440 / 610 = 2.36.  Grossed up hits = 23,607

I tried a calculating datepart but got SQL error: datetime2 incompatible with int.

Would CAST help?  I'm not that versed on manipulating date values.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempt(s) will help us help you.

Comment: Show us the code which fails. Ideally, show us the relevent table definition as well. When you say "timestamp", you don't mean the actual sql server `timestamp` datatype, do you?

Answer (score 0):

`datetime2 incompatible with int` => Date requires to be wrapped with single quotes eg. `'2020-07-13'`

Do you have a date anywhere in your code that isn't wrapped with a single quote (which becomes a number).
`2020-07-13 = 2020 minus 07 minus 13 = 2000`

Edit:
It may also occur when attempting to perform a multiplication of datetime/datetime2 with a number. After a chat in the comments section, it seems like this was the issue.

Comment: code is referencing the latest timestamp:  ,MAX ([Time_Utc]) AS 'Max Time'

Comment: Maybe share some code? It would remove a lot of guesswork on what you are trying to do.

Comment: SELECT  [Date_utc]
,FORMAT(sum([hit_Tot]), 'N0') AS 'hits'
,newRunRate = (sum([hit_Tot]) * 1440) / (DATEPART(hour, MAX ([Time_Utc])*60))

Comment: `MAX ([Time_Utc])*60` => is the problem. What are you trying to do? Maybe move the *60 outside the ). `DATEPART(hour, MAX ([Time_Utc])*60)` => `DATEPART(hour, MAX ([Time_Utc]))*60`

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the 24 hour run rate based on a value a timestamp that reflects < 24hrs.  For example if hits are 500 and timestamp is 6:00am, then the 24hr runrate would be 2,000 (500 per 6 hrs = 2,000 per 24 hrs).

Comment: ok. So you want total minutes in a day / (datedif between timestamp 12:00 AM in the morning in minutes) * 500 , no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217755/discussion-between-coding-newbie-and-sudip-shrestha).